# Windows 8.1 small grey boxes on the corners of icons

Tags: windows-8.1

this is annoying me because i am trying to have a 3d desktop, and i have the size on medium. i *think* this doesn't depend on the size, because the box is still there afterwards. if you can't see them, you can probably zoom in for the best quality.

[image]

best example is the b. icon

Comment: I don't see any grey boxes :/

Answer (score 0):

This [technet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3a2c3814-ab1d-4a7b-bf6d-c825aedb2c5a/strange-outline-around-some-desktop-icons-now-a-different-question?forum=w7itproui) seems to be relevant to your issue.

Click on your desktop then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Mouse Wheel to change the size of the icons. This should remove the gray square.

You can also right click on the desktop, click "View", then change the size of your icons away from Medium.

Lastly, try a refresh on your desktop. Right click on the desktop and click "Refresh"